# Image caption with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an Image with a border above it and I want a caption that slides 'between' them on hovering the image. I just can't get it working the way I want, what I have is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">

        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js " type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.boxGrid').hover(function(){
                    $('.boxCaption', this).stop().animate({bottom:'0px'},{queue:false,duration:300});
                }, function() {
                    $('.boxCaption', this).stop().animate({bottom:'-121px'},{queue:false,duration:300});
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="boxGrid"></div>
            <div class="buttonBack blogImg">
                <div class="boxCaption">
                    <h3>Top-Blog</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

*css*

```
.wrapper
{
    position: relative;
    width: 226px;
    height: 246px;
}

.boxGrid
{
    width: 226px;
    height: 246px;
    background-image: url(http://s10.postimage.org/z2cp1i70p/button_Border.png);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 100;
}

.buttonBack
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    left: 13px;
    border: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 223px;
    z-index: 50;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.blogImg
{
    background-image: url(http://s10.postimage.org/jflfo4t8p/blog_Button.png);
}

.boxCaption
{
    position: absolute;  
    background: url(http://s10.postimage.org/c2an2wykp/caption.png);
    height: 121px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: -121px;
    text-align: center;
}

.boxCaption h3
{
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

But when I adit the html and jQuery like this, it works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">

        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js " type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.buttonBack').hover(function(){
                    $('.boxCaption', this).stop().animate({bottom:'0px'},{queue:false,duration:300});
                }, function() {
                    $('.boxCaption', this).stop().animate({bottom:'-121px'},{queue:false,duration:300});
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <!--<div class="boxGrid"></div>-->
            <div class="buttonBack blogImg">
                <div class="boxCaption">
                    <h3>Top-Blog</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I did is commenting the `div.boxGrid` out and let the jQuery function execute on hovering the `div.buttonBack` in place of the `div.boxGrid`. Only that's not what I want, I want the `div.boxGrid` to be above all that, so I get [this](http://s13.postimage.org/6g2taf7s7/blogknop_mouseover_2_large.png) effect on hovering.

I've made a jsFiddle, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wBjT3/2/) it doesn't work, but [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/wBjT3/3/) it works...

Any help would be much appreciated, I'm pulling my hair out on this one.

Comment: There is no code in the fiddle?

Comment: Weird, if I open the link, there is code! (exept the jQuery)

Comment: thats what I meant, your jQuery code is not in the fiddle

Comment: Sorry, see my updated question. @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `boxGrid` class has higher `z-index` than `buttonBack` class. Fix it and then try...

See the link : http://jsfiddle.net/wBjT3/5/

Comment: I know, but that's what I want, I want the `.boxGrid` to be above the image so I get [this](http://s13.postimage.org/6g2taf7s7/blogknop_mouseover_2_large.png) effect. Thanks anyway!